# Html Video Tag Cannot load local path

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-video

I have a React App running as a WebView inside an iOS app. When I require the files from the iOS app, the app will return the files with the their local paths in the iOS device.

The data looks like

```
file: {
  thumbnail: "file:///var/mobile/C......png",
  path: "file:///var/mobile/C......mp4",
}
```

And in the React app, I then use the paths and the html video tag to play the video.

```
<video poster={file.thumbnail}>
  <source src={file.path} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

And the result is that the poster can be successfully loaded, but the video file itself cannot be.

my question is, if there's some problems with the `url` being a local path, then the `poster` should also fail. So why it's only the video source that fails? Is it because I missed something? Or is it because the `poster` and the `source` is handled differently behind the scene so that it's only the `source` that fails?

Answer (score 1):

You can move video and images file into your project and save them in assets. I think it will make it easier, and the "path" will not be long like that, readable.
Just my opinion.

Comment: Thx for your input. The files are dynamically added in the iOS app by the users. But anyways, my question was why the poster can be loaded, and the video itself cannot be.